# Need author, title, source for short story with translation game -- short phrases translated through six languages back to original

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The title says it all -- a short story, published a few decades ago, where a subplot is a game where a phrase (e.g. time heals all wounds) is run through an auto-translater of 5 other languages and then back into the original language. The game is to figure out the original phrase from what the final translation shows.

Comment: What is the science fiction or fantasy aspect? If there isn't one, you need to ask this in the Literature SE.

Comment: @fuzzyboots Depending on when it was written, the "auto-translator" might have been science fiction...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Galactic Pot-Healer**

I believe this is not a short story, but chapter one of Philip K. Dick's 1969 novel *Galactic Pot-Healer*. In it, the protagonist, Joe Fernwright, plays "The Game" by phone with people from other countries. "The Game" consists of riddles where a phrase has been autotranslated from English to e.g. Russian and back, and the object is to guess the original phrase. For example, the book title "The Latticework Gun Stinging Insect" was originally "The Great Gatsby" (Grate Gat Bee).

You can hear the book as an audiobook on YouTube. Here is the [link to Chapter One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acFcu8K2NHg). The Game is described from ca. 10:00 onwards.

Comment: Thank you -- I will check that out.

Comment: I did check it out -- as usual, my memory had some kernel of truth, but was seriously distorted. This is in fact the game I was trying to remember. Thanks again.

Comment: @babyboomer -- if, as you mention in the comment, this is the answer to your question, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the question.  And....welcome to to SF&F StackExchange!

Comment: Done. Thanks. I did look over some other questions, but did not know any answers.